# How to understand my Twitter data frame pivot

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I am trying to create a heat map of my Twitter activity. I would like to map my activity over a week to see the best days and hours for engagement.

Here is what I have done so far:

- I have extracted my Twitter in a pandas dataframe
- Created separate columns for the day of the tweet and hour of the
  tweet
- Created a separate column for if the tweet got a retweet or not

When I run the below code, I get decimal place figures instead of number of retweets.

```
pivoted_df = tweets.pivot_table(index='hour_of_tweet', columns='day_of_tweet', values='retweet_count')
pivoted_df = pivoted_df[['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']]
pivoted_df = pivoted_df.replace(np.nan,0)
pivoted_df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues')
```

This is the output:

[image]

I also double checked the retweet_counts column using `series.value_counts()`. The values are whole integers, there are no fractional values.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I realised there are additional arguments such as aggfunc and fill_value. I set these to 'sum' and '0' respectively and now its much tidier!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuqwl.jpg